# How can you restore data from postgres backup, into table that allready has data in it

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I want to restore data from production server in to our testing env. I need only 3 tables from production db. And have created 3 different backups (.backup) files for each with `pg_dump -h localhost -U user --table my_table -Fc -f my_table.backup db` command.

When I try to copy data from backups to desired tables with pg_restore (`pg_restore -d db -U user --table desired_table my_table.backup`) i get the following errors:

```
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 234; 1259 16514 TABLE "my_table" user
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "table" already exists
Command was: CREATE TABLE public.table (....);


pg_restore: from TOC entry 3277; 0 16514 TABLE DATA my_table db

pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "my_table": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"

DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3) already exists.

CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 2

pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 2
```

I know that duplicate keys are problem, but how can I avoid this and just add the data from my_table backup's to the wanted tables with existing data in it ?

Comment: If you want to ignore the constraints, then drop them.  If you want to do something else, then explain what that something else is.

Comment: How do you drop them ?  If i remove the id’s, then while adding them in table, they will be assigned a new ones, and there will be no conflicts ? Did you mean that ?  
Or something else ? 
Thank’s for answering..

Comment: No, I meant drop the unique/primary key constraints.  You can do that with `ALTER TABLE` or `DROP INDEX`.  Removing the columns and letting them be assigned automatically could also work, but that would be a lot of editing of files.  If you want to do that, it would be easier to just dump them with \COPY and load with \COPY.  Of course if the tables have foreign keys between them, those would get garbled (with either method)

Comment: It turned out almost impossible to do it in the way I intended. Since every table had constraints between each other. Only solution for now, for me, is to backup whole db.